# Какую выбрать книгу для изучения PHP?

Tags: php, книги

Здравствуйте. Хочу научиться писать на PHP. Понятно, что это дело не одной прочитанной книги, но всё же помогите определиться с первой. Выбор лежит между "PHP 5" (Автор: Дмитрий Котеров, Алексей Костарев) и "Разработка веб-приложений с помощью PHP и MySQL" (Автор: Люк Веллинг, Лора Томсон). Обе книги хвалят и рекомендуют.

Comment: вторую не рекомендую. а вот Котерова почитай. как по мне она лучшая для начинающих

Comment: А чем плоха вторая книга? Вроде бы авторы стараются рассматривать язык на примерах из реальной практики. Или это и есть слабое место книги?

Comment: не надо читать книги, они **всегда** содержат информацию устаревшую на момент публикации.

Comment: > они всегда содержат информацию устаревшую на момент публикаци

почему же так категорично? Языки не настолько быстро развиваются, чтобы книги скажем годичной давности можно было назвать устаревшими. Не скажу насчет стандартизации PHP, но для большинства языков новые стандарты входят раз в 5-10 лет, а новые версии пусть и чаще, но их изменения обычно не настолько основополагающи, чтобы целую книгу считать устаревшей. Тем более, что для новичка чаще всего какие-то новые возможности поначалу не очень важны.

Comment: @DreamChild - потому что книга издается минимум три года. За это время меняется не только сам язык но и производственный процесс, тренды и прочее. Только недавно был деятель с книжкой от Лауры в которой не только использовалось расширение mysql но и паттерны кода были из начала двухтысячных. 

Информацию по языку нужно получать из официальной документации. Нюансы спрашивать на форумах и IRC.

Comment: Если говорить про переводные издания - я соглашусь @eicto. Но книги на английском языке издаются довольно шустро и содержат свежую информацию!

Comment: Если цель просто изучить PHP - то книгу можно брать любую, т.к. основы языка везде объясняются одинаково. Читаете через главу, периодически заглядываете в официальную документацию, попутно смотрите листинги чужого кода и разбираетесь. А если при этом знание\понимание программирования на нуле - то лучше от PHP держаться подальше.

Comment: Ну вот взять того-же Костерова 2е издание (не переводной, 2008г), так - для индикации всё еще использует mysql_connect(). 

@zhenyab название актуальной книжки по php дайте на английском.

Comment: Programming PHP5 O'Reilly, например. Вообще для начинающих O'Reilly это хороший выбор, на мой взгляд

Comment: Так в частности мануал по php можно рассматривать как книгу. Вполне себе доходчивым языком написано. А просто научившись читать документацию, осваивать языки и фреймворки гораздо проще, а так-же это дает скилл писать свою документацию и задавать правильные вопросы.
Что касается книг по программированию вообще - я ничего против не имею.

> Ну и в-пятых, у изучения по мануалам и форумам есть один недостаток - отсутствие систематизированности.

что извините ? Я про мануалы. Обычно в них всё систематизировано. Одна сущность называется одним образом и пр, кроссылки расставлены.

Answer (score 3):

Я не уверен, что для изучения PHP нужно читать именно книги. В свое время, когда только начинал разбираться с PHP, просто взял, и начал подряд читать [этот](http://www.php.su/lessons/) раздел (не знаю на сколько там актуальна информация сейчас). Проходится он быстро, знакомит с базовыми понятиями. Я, например, после прочтения начал пробовать "писать" более-менее серьезный сайт (тогда это была система учета и контроля листов рекламаций для техники, сданной в ремонт).

Уже в процессе создания системы ознакамливался с [этим](http://www.php.su/learnphp/) разделом, а затем перекопал весь этот ресурс и начал ходить за офф. документацией (на тот момент на русском ее было очень мало). Как результат, сам сайт два раза переписывался почти с нуля и постоянно допиливался.

Я считаю, что делать упор стоит не на книги, а на "практику". Изучать маны, разбирать чужой код, знакомиться с Best practice, и постоянно пробовать, пробовать и еще раз пробовать все это на своих проектах.

Для того, чтобы "начать" - этого вполне достаточно. Например, я за книги взялся, когда начал активно изучать шаблоны проектирования и в частности использование их в PHP.

Comment: конечно, нужно сначала собрать шкаф. Если останутся детали - то посмотреть инструкцию. Не все способны к такого рода самообучению! Кому-то сподручнее учебник/книгу почитать. И РНР это, или ASP значения не имеет. Единственно с чем соглашусь - это как можно больше практики!

Comment: Вторая книга, ИМХО, самая лучшая из всех, что я читал. Большая часть книг по php устарели, а эта—нет.